# Facing issue in starting geth client

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am using geth client(private network).
When I try to start my network it shows "segmentation fault".
Can you guide how to solve this issues?

> ```
> go-ethereum/build/bin/geth  --mine  --nodiscover  --maxpeers 0  --networkid 13  --rpc  --rpccorsdomain "*"
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

Comment: Delete the `data` folder if it exists on your path, and add `--datadir ./data` to your geth command-line.

Comment: Thank you for ur response. Their is no data folder in existing path. Still i am getting this error                                                                                                         
  go-ethereum/build/bin/geth  --datadir ./data
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: By re-installing geth issues resolved.